# Nextjs Images look FRIED with fill settings

Tags: image, next.js, airtable

I am attempting to make profile cards. When I use fill/contain, the images look great but are not filling the circular div:

[image]

And when I use fill/cover, they are the circular profile pics I want but the images themselves look a bit fried. Adding the unoptimized parameter did not help.

[image]

What would be the best way to solve this? Thank you so much!

```
                        {image ?
                                <Image
                                    loader={myLoader}
                                    className={'profileImage'}
                                    src={profileImage}
                                    alt={'Profile picture of ' + profile.fields.Name}
                                    layout={'fill'}
                                    objectFit={'contain'}
                                    unoptimized={false}
                                    quality={100}
                                    loading={"eager"}
                                    priority = {index < 10 ? true : false}
                                />
                            :
                            <div className="avatarWrapper ">
                                <Avatar
                                    size={'12vh'}
                                    ...
```

Comment: try giving `style={{width: "100%", height: "auto"}}` to Image element while using contain.

Comment: Could You provide link to the repo please ?

Comment: Sorry, @MohammedJunaid, didn't work. :/

Comment: @MarioG8, here you go, but be warned: it's a hot mess. https://github.com/zanewolf/osah/blob/main/components/ProfileCard.js

Comment: you can also play with it here: https://www.oceanscholars.org/people

Comment: did you try `objectFit='scale-down'` ?

Comment: objectFit is unfortunately deprecated as a prop in the latest version of next/image